# Window control not leaving memory between instantiations

Tags: c#, wpf

Possibly important info:

I am using WPF, not winforms.

WPF structure of the PrintPanelViewbox is

```
viewbox <panel < "Panel1" = <image/> "Panel2" = <image/> "Panel3" = <image/> /> />
```

.Net Framework 4.5.2, Visual Studio 2017, windows 7 and 10 (testing for both)

---

I have a small section of code which displays a preview window to a user as a dialog.  That section works as follows.

```
        if (/*there is something to preview*/)
        {
            Window window = new Window
            {
                Width = 300,
                Height = 600,
                MinWidth = 300,
                MinHeight = 600,
                MaxWidth = 300,
                MaxHeight = 600,
                Title = "Current Preview",
                Content = this.PrintPanelViewbox,
            };

            window.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is nothing to preview.");
        }
```

TL;DR w/ question at bottom.

This is the entire method that is called to pull up the preview window.  I would expect that upon leaving the if ()true {block}, the temporary variable window will fall out of scope and be cleared out.  However this behavior is not true.

If I open a preview with my PrintPanelViewbox in any given configuration, it usually works fine.  However, once that has been opened once, if I change the configuration of child of the PrintPanelViewbox (which is a panel, I wrap it in a viewbox for nicer scaling) and run this method to open the preview window again, the preview window does NOT update it's layout.

Ok I think, so I try all of the following to force recursive updating among children:

```
window.InvalidateArrange();
window.UpdateLayout();

window.Content = null; //after running successfully

window.InvalidateVisual();
```

And other, similar calls on both the preview window and the PrintPanelViewbox in every configuration I can think of.  I even went as far as thread locking the UI thread on every call just to see if it was an asynchronous update that was taking longer than the preview window took to display.

No matter what I do, the preview window seems to always remember the last displayed state when it pulls up.

Now the really weird part.

If I run the method to show the preview window again after it failed to show the contents of the PrintPanelViewbox once, it shows it correctly.  I change nothing, I simply run that method 2 times.  The first it is always wrong, the second it is correct.

This tells me that somehow the rendering is NOT being updated despite the control falling out of scope AND it's children being altered.  So I decided to force a re-rendering the only way I could think of.

I added a variable which switches between 1 and 0 each time the preview window is displayed, then added it to the window's width and height settings.  This means that each time the window is displayed to the user, it has a 1 pixel size difference, forcing a re-rendering of its contents.  This method works and the window shows properly the first time, every time.

Basically I have confirmed that the out of scope window variable is still sitting in the operating system's visual ["retained mode"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview#visual-rendering-behavior) and not calling a re-render event when I'm changing the children because the child is still the "same" child each time the window is actually shown to the user..

---

TL;DR

My final question is, how do I force this window to actually re-render?  It does not have a dispose method, and since the child variable is the same (despite its children changing) since it is a viewbox and I do want the fixed 300 x 600 window size, I can't get it to update or leave the "retained" state.

Comment: An effective solution would be to use the MVVM pattern instead of constructing your view in code. Then you won't need these ugly `InvalidateVisual` calls.

Comment: If using MVVM pattern, won't I still run into a similar problem when trying to show a window that only has child of child changes?  It's not a pattern I am familiar enough with (obviously) and this program was not meant to be scale-able and robust, just a quick thing to blast out a few labels that needed some logic under them.  Using WPF purely to leverage viewbox scaling for printing, not the myriad of other advantages it brings.